# Converting datetime to month-year only - T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I want to convert a dateTime value to Month-Year (note the **(-)** between them).

i want them like Jan-2014, Feb-2014, Mar-2014, Apr-2014.

i have tried

```
SELECT convert(varchar(7), getdate(), 126) 
SELECT right(convert(varchar, getdate(), 106), 8)
```

But the first line gives me 2014-05 (i need it like May-2014) while the second line gives May 2014 (its missing the -, as in May-2014)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
SELECT replace(right(convert(varchar, getdate(), 106), 8), ' ', '-')
```

Comment: so is the resulting value a datetime or a string?

Comment: Do u know the equivalent of the same for micorosoft access database engine? In SQL server it runs ok, in Access it gives undefined function convert.

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about Access. Probably you can use some VBA function (it's Format, I believe).

Answer (score 1):

Write as:

```
SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),
                     GETDATE(), 106), 8),
                     ' ', '-') AS [Mon-YYYY]
```

Answer (score 1):

i think convert my not be the correct approach.
try this:

```
select substring(DATENAME(M,GETDATE()),1,3)+'-'+DATENAME(YYYY,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT(CHAR(4), getdate(), 100) +'-'+ CONVERT(CHAR(4),  getdate(), 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  CONVERT(CHAR(4), GETDATE(), 100) +'-'+ CONVERT(CHAR(4), GETDATE(), 120)
```