# SQL - Monthly cumulative count of new customer based on a created date field

Tags: sql

Thanks in advance.

I have Customer records that look like this:

| Customer_Number | Create_Date |
| --- | --- |
| 34343 | 01/22/2001 |
| 54554 | 03/03/2020 |
| 85296 | 01/01/2001 |
| ... |  |

I have about a thousand of these records (customer number is unique) and the bossman wants to see how the number of customers has grown over time.

The output I need:

| Customer_Count | Monthly_Bucket |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 01/01/2021 |
| 9 | 02/01/2021 |
| 13 | 03/01/2021 |
| 20 | 04/01/2021 |

The customer count is *cumulative* and the Monthly Bucket will just feed the graphing package to make a nice bar chart answering the question "how many customers to we have in total in a particular month and how is it growing over time".

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table GROUPBY Create_Date `

Comment: Firstly, thanks for reformatting it!
Secondly, I need to group them by months. Counting the number or records created in a particular month AND before then. A cumulative count.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490031/converting-datetime-to-month-year-only-t-sql

Answer (score 0):

Try the following SELECT SQL with a sub-query:

```
SELECT Customer_Count=
(
    SELECT COUNT(s.[Create_Date])  
    FROM [Customer_Sales] s
    WHERE MONTH(s.[Create_Date]) <= MONTH(t.[Create_Date])
), Monthly_Bucket=MONTH([Create_Date])
FROM Customer_Sales t
WHERE YEAR(t.[Create_Date]) = ????
GROUP BY MONTH(t.[Create_Date])
```

Where [Customer_Sales] is the sales table and ??? = your year